# Disallow viewing list items

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

Suppose there's a `top-secret` list (inherits its permissions from its parent) that contains records that were created earlier by different users. There are several groups with rights to administer, read, write-constrainted.

There is a group of authors of `top-secret items`. Author can only create a 'secret-item'. *`But the item shouldn't be viewed by other participants of the group (Authors).`*

I can't access/change site programmatically. And I'm curious how come I do this manually.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask non-programmatic SharePoint questions

Comment: Good point! But I asked it there too. And got a programmatic answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, keep in mind that you cannot do "top-secret" in SharePoint. The site collection administrator will always have access to all content.

Manually, there are two features that come close to your request:

- under advanced options in the list settings: user can only read/write his/her own items
- under the same advanced options: activate approval. Content in draft state will remain hidden (except from approvers and site owners)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers from @Christophe, you can also modify the permissions of individual List Items.

If you were able to make programmatic changes, I would suggest attaching an ItemAdded event receiver to a custom Content Type named "Top Secret." But in this case, the permissions changes can be made as a manual step after adding the item.

The risk, of course, is if the author forgets to change the permissions, changes the permissions incorrectly, or changes the permissions very slowly (allowing others to see it before permissions are changed).

For more information on changing the permissions of a List Item, see [Break permission inheritance on a folder, document, or list item](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/manage-permissions-for-a-list-library-folder-document-or-list-item-HA010021564.aspx#BM10).